# Why does my JavaScript setter not change object property as expected?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have `users` array (of objects) inside a JavaScript object. Every user has an `isActive` property:

```
let groups = {
  groupId: 0,
  userRights: {
    users: [{
      name: 'John',
      isActive: true
    },
    {
      name: 'Marry',
      isActive: true
    }
  ]},
  set userStatus(user) {
    this.userRights.users.forEach(function(user) {
      // On this condition, change users statuses
      if(parseInt(this.groupId) !== 1){
       user.isActive = false;
      }
    });
  },
}

console.log(groups.userRights.users);
```

I was expecting my setter to change every user's `isActive` proprty to `false` so I could see it in the console already changes.

What am doing wrong?

Comment: you need to assign value to `userStatus` in order to call `set` function code. `groups.userStatus = 10;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the setter, but not calling it anywhere.

You need to call the setter you defined using `groups.userStatus = value;`.

And on a side note, I renamed the setter to `userStatusAll` as I believe it's more specific.

```js
let groups = {
  groupId: 1,
  userRights: {
    users: [{
      name: 'John',
      isActive: true
    },
    {
      name: 'Marry',
      isActive: true
    }
  ]},

  //defining the setter
  set userStatusAll(user) {
    this.userRights.users.forEach(function(user) {
      user.isActive = false;
    });
  },
}

groups.userStatusAll = false; //calling the setter with value of false
console.log(groups.userRights.users);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the value to userStatus in order to call the set function. I refactored the function to accept status and user name, to match only a single user and change it's status.

```js
let groups = {
  groupId: 1,
  userRights: {
    users: [{
      name: 'John',
      isActive: true
    },
    {
      name: 'Marry',
      isActive: true
    }
  ]},
  set userStatus({ userName, userStatus }) {
    this.userRights.users.forEach(function(user) {
      if(user.name === userName){
         user.isActive = userStatus;
      }
    });
  },
}

groups.userStatus = { userName: 'John', userStatus: false };
console.log(groups.userRights)
```